# Selected value being read with lag

Tags: reactjs, strict

I am trying to learn React by doing. Somehow, I am missing something very silly here.
I have 2 calendars in my code. And I have used console logging to debug, as can be seen in the code.

```
import React, { useState } from  'react';
import {DatePicker} from 'rsuite';
import './styles.css';
import { AppContext } from '../Context';

function DateRangePickerCal(){
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState("0");
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState("0");

  const updateSelection = () =>{
    console.log("Method Update Selection called.")
    if(document.getElementById('toDate').value !== undefined){
      setEndDate(document.getElementById('toDate').value);
    }
    if(document.getElementById('fromDate').value !== undefined){
      setStartDate(document.getElementById('fromDate').value);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(document.getElementById('toDate').value));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(document.getElementById('fromDate').value)); 
  }
return ( 
  <div>
    <DatePicker onChange={updateSelection} id="toDate" appearance="default" placeholder="Default" style={{ width: 230 }} />
   <DatePicker onChange={updateSelection} id="fromDate" appearance="default" placeholder="Default1" style={{ width: 230 }} />
   </div>
);

}
export default DateRangePickerCal;
```

But I am seeing the following in the console: (*The browser is rendering output from other components also.*)

[image]

While trying to debug this I noticed that if I keep on changing the selection in the second calendar, it picks the correct value with lag.

I am not sure, if it is due to the '`React.StrictMode`'

Please help me and please also let me know if there can be other reasons.

Comment: You should avoid using `document.getElement...` in React, instead use [refs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs)